# How to receive and handle response from the Php Script while using it with jQuery Ajax method

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

How can I receive and handle the response from a PHP Script while using a jQuery Ajax method?

**javascript**

```js
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: 'show.php',
    data: {name: name},
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(response) {
       //I want my json response back here
    }
});
```

**show.php**

```php
$hostelName = $_POST['name'];
$sql = //here is the actual sql containing the $hostelname
$query = mysql_query($sql);
$obj = mysql_fetch_object($query); 
$sum = $obj->sum;
$tour = $obj->tour;
echo json_encode(
    array(
        "sum" => $sum,
        "tour" => $tour
    )
);
```

Comment: Are you facing any issue while doing this?

Comment: Your PHP code does no error checking at all, that's going to cause all kinds of issues if, for example, the database can't be connected to or if the query doesn't return any rows.  Also, mysql_* functions are deprecated and shouldn't be used in new code.  Use mysqli or PDO instead

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
    $.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: 'show.php',
    data: "name="+ name,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(response) {
    //here I'd like back the php query
    }
```

and your PHP code to this:

```
    $hostelName =mysql_escape_string($_POST['name']);

    $sql = //here is the actual sql containing the $hostelname

    $query = mysql_query($sql);

    $reusult = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
    echo json_encode($reusult);
```

Comment: It's worth noting that user input (`$hostelName`) needs to be escaped prior to injecting it into `$sql`, otherwise the OP will have a SQL injection vulnerability.

Answer (score 1):

In your PHP code you are returning response as JSON. so just need to parse as below in code snippet

```
 $.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: 'show.php',
    data: {name: name},
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(response) {
       //response is json you need to parse it
         var json = response,
         obj = JSON.parse(json);
         alert(obj.sum);
         alert(obj.tour);

    }
```